# Perl DBI Constants - how to access?

Tags: sql, perl, dbi, subroutine

The documentation for [getting type info](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.623/DBI.pm#type_info_all) includes this piece of suggested code for getting the mapping between code and integer:

```
foreach (@{ $DBI::EXPORT_TAGS{sql_types} }) {
    printf "%s=%d\n", $_, &{"DBI::$_"};
}
```

But perl 5.16.2 won't allow it:

```
Can't use string ("DBI::SQL_GUID") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use
```

I don't know how to turn off **strict refs** and I suspect it wasn't the author's intention that anyone do so.  How can this subroutine call be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn off strict 'refs' by doing this

```
{
    no strict 'refs';
    foreach (@{ $DBI::EXPORT_TAGS{sql_types} }) {
        printf "%s=%d\n", $_, &{"DBI::$_"};
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why would you put `no strict 'refs';` on the outside? The following is more appropriate use of `no strict 'refs';`:

```
for (@{ $DBI::EXPORT_TAGS{sql_types} }) {
    no strict 'refs';
    printf "%s=%d\n", $_, &{"DBI::$_"};
}
```

(And don't say anything about jmcneirney's being a microsecond faster because that would be wrong.)

Or, since `\&` isn't subject to a strict refs check,

```
for (@{ $DBI::EXPORT_TAGS{sql_types} }) {
    my $ref = \&{"DBI::$_"};
    printf "%s=%d\n", $_, $ref->();
}
```